# Ruby: "undefined method" error; how to use gsub more effectively?

Tags: ruby, gsub

So I'm trying to find a way to Donald Duck-ify statements inputed by users (judge me later).

This is my code so far:

```
puts "Wanna get Donald Duck-ified?"
print "Type some text here:"
user_input = gets.chomp

if user_input.gsub!(/s/,"th").gsub!(/ce/,"th").gsub!(/ci/,"th").gsub!(/cy/,"th")
    puts "Boop - there go your s's and soft c's!"
else
    puts "Dang, you didn't have any s's or soft c's!"
end

puts "#{user_input}"
```

Upon testing it with some input of my own ("square cycle caesar circle", specifically), I'm getting "undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass" as an error.

How is gsub! undefined? If the code runs with `user_input.gsub!(/s/,"th")` on it own, without any other methods behind it, it works fine. Once a second method is added, the `else` code runs and only replacements for "s" are made. All four and I get the error above.

**Does there happen to be another way of substituting multiple patterns (as named by the Ruby docs) with a single replacement?** I've spent the last hours researching the problem and I still can't totally tell what the issue is.

New to Ruby. Encouraged and motivated.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Don't* use [`#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) chained. (Actually, *don't* use `#gsub!` at all for most code.)

> [gsub!] Performs the substitutions of String#gsub *in place*, returning str, *or nil* if no substitutions were performed.

Switch the code to [`#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) which doesn't cause side-effects (yay!) and always returns a string (yay!) - simply compare the result with the original (unmodified) string.

---

Also, one could use the gsub form that accepts a hash (since Ruby 1.9.something). This has a subtle difference that replaced values will not be themselves replaced, although it doesn't matter here.

```
user_input.gsub(/s|ce|ci|cy/, { "s"=>"th", "ce"=>"th", "ci"=>"th", "cy"=>"th" })
# or since all are replaced with "th" (which I just noticed =^_^=) ..
user_input.gsub(/s|ce|ci|cy/, "th")
```

(I still recommend against `gsub!` because I find side effects upon strings disconcerting. However, it would work reliably when used with the non-chained forms above.)

Comment: Both your examples - especially the second one - are exactly what I've been trying to do all this time! They worked too, albeit once I added the `!` in front of the method. I'll definitely keep your recommendation in mind for the future. I now have another dilemna: I have this set to replace "ci/ce/cy" with, for "circle", will give me "thrcle", haha. Now to figure out how to RECOGNIZE words starting with "ci" and REPLACING the "c" only. When you've solved one, along come another, haha. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) returns `nil` if it performs no substitutions. This means you can't reliably chain it like you do. If you want to verify that any of the `gsub`s have made any change, you can chain non-destructive `gsub`s (without the bang; return a new string instead of modifying the current one) instead:

```
input = gets.chomp
replaced = input.gsub(/s/,"th").gsub(/ce/,"th").gsub(/ci/,"th").gsub(/cy/,"th")
if input == replaced
  ...
```

Comment: Nice method of verifying. I will most definitely keep that in mind as I continue to use gsub. Thanks!